# Bartlett test error (at least 2 observations) to check homoscedasticity

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, diagnostic

I've got this data.frame (framingham)

```
     sex sbp  bmi
1 female 130 24.0
2   male 126 29.0
3 female 146 26.6
4   male 116 20.8
5 female 100 20.9
6 female 128 26.8
```

that I splitted into framinghamMales and framinghamFemales:

```
> head(framinghamMales)
      sex sbp  bmi
2    male 126 29.0
4    male 116 20.8
7    male 115 25.0
9    male 155 28.8
10   male 118 26.7
13   male 128 27.9

> head(framinghamFemales)
     sex sbp  bmi
1 female 130 24.0
3 female 146 26.6
5 female 100 20.9
6 female 128 26.8
8 female 124 30.4
11female 128 20.4
```

I've made two models for a regression and now I want to make a Bartlett test to check homoscedasticity, but when I try it I get this error:

```
> bartlett.test(sbp~bmi, data = framingham)
Error in bartlett.test.default(c(130, 126, 146, 116, 100, 128, 115, 124,  : 
  there must be at least 2 observations in each group
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I check homoscedasticity correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're a getting is because the input you're giving has one observation each (one "bmi" observation per "sbp"). Replace "sbp" by "sex" (which is your explanatory variable in this case) in your formula -make sure "sex" is a factor and not character:

This is what I get:

`r bartlett.test(framinghman$bmi, framinghman$sex)`

`Bartlett test of homogeneity of variances
data: framinghman$bmi and framinghman$sex
Bartlett's K-squared = 0.20515, df = 1, p-value = 0.6506`

Hope this helps.